# Detecting mobile SMS reader previews

Tags: php

I have a page that sends out pincodes for validation when you visit. They get sent via sms - and alot of the latest updates for both ios and android actually previews urls they receive. so my page sends them their pincodes before actually them clicking the links.

Doing some testing ive found that android browser user agent contains "X11", so ive found a way of limiting that. then i went on to ios and see that their preview contains the useragent : "Macintosh".

However, i cant get this to work:

```
if(strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"X11")) <= 0 || strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Macintosh")) <= 0 ){ 
//Send out pin since this isnt a sms browser preview
}
```

it works if i only have X11, but not with the additional Macintosh check. any ideas?

Comment: Well, it's unlikely that something will meet _both_ of those conditions, so _one_ of them will always be true.  You're using `||` (an OR).  See why it's always getting into the condition?

Comment: you know how you work yourself blind on these things? thanks alot pal, i know what to do now.